# How do I check which guardian types I've defeated?

Tags: achievements, sonic-frontiers

The "Threats Identified" achievement says "Defeated all guardian types". How do I check which guardian types I've defeated so far? Do I just need to try fighting every guardian again until I find the ones I missed?